# sync rosserial arduino

Tags: ros, rosseral-arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There was a couple of seconds a couple of seconds ago a question regarding rosserial arduino I accidentally deleted (I wanted to delete my own comment but accidentally deleted the entire question), sorry.

The issue was after running rosrun `rosserial_python serial_node.py _port:=/dev/ttyACM0` the error `unable to sync with device occurred.`

The code looked quite like the example service client code but with a custom message (does not matter for the issue) and some parts commented out:

```
/*
 * rosserial Service Client
 */

    #include <ros.h>
    #include <std_msgs/String.h>
    #include <rosserial_arduino/Test.h>
    
    ros::NodeHandle  nh;
    using rosserial_arduino::Test;
    
    ros::ServiceClient<Test::Request, Test::Response> client("test_srv");
    
//    std_msgs::String str_msg;
//    ros::Publisher chatter("chatter", &str_msg);
    
//    char hello[13] = "hello world!";
    
    void setup()
    {
      nh.initNode();
      nh.serviceClient(client);
  //    nh.advertise(chatter);
      while(!nh.connected()) nh.spinOnce();
      nh.loginfo("Startup complete");
    }
    
    void loop()
    {
      Test::Request req;
      Test::Response res;
      req.input = hello;
      client.call(req, res);
   //   str_msg.data = res.output;
   //   chatter.publish( &str_msg );
   //  nh.spinOnce();
      delay(100);
    }
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199351/sync-rosserial-arduino/) by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7555 on 2014-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue is caused by commenting out the `nh.spinOnce()`. It is still needed for topic negotiation between serial_node and device, eventhough the publisher is not used anymore

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mind_hunter](https://answers.ros.org/users/19892/mind_hunter/) on 2014-12-12**:
Ok , I have uncommented it but still server is not getting the client request .

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-12-12**:
Do you still get the error with "unable to sync with device ... groovy ... hydro " ...

**Comment by [Mind_hunter](https://answers.ros.org/users/19892/mind_hunter/) on 2014-12-13**:
" Sync with device lost." this is showing